# angular2 routerOnActivate is not called

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing

I have the following components, one main and another. I would like to navigate programmatically from main to another.

**Main**

```
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/angular2/core.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/angular2/router.d.ts" />

import {Component, provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig, Router, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';

@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/Main/...', name: 'Main', component: Main}
])
@Component({
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS],
    selector: 'Main',
    template:
    '<div>
        <button type="button" (click)="navigate()">Navigate</button>
    </div>'
})
export class Main {
    constructor(private _router: Router) { }

    navigate() {
        this._router.navigateByUrl('Another');
    }
}
```

**Another**

```
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/angular2/core.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/angular2/router.d.ts" />

import {Component, provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig, Router, ComponentInstruction, OnActivate,    ROUTER_PROVIDERS, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';

@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/Another/...', name: 'Another', component: Another}
])
@Component({
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS],
    selector: 'Another',
    template:
    '<div [style.display]="isActive()">
        <h1>i'm another!</h1>
    </div>'
})
export class Another implements OnActivate {
    constructor(private _router: Router) { }

    IsActive = false;

    isActive() {
        return (this.IsActive === true) ? 'block' : 'none';
    }

    routerOnActivate(next: ComponentInstruction, prev: ComponentInstruction) {
        this.IsActive = true;
        console.log("called! surprisingly.");
    }
}
```

It seems that `routerOnActivate` is never called, although the URL in the browser shows `Main/Another`. Why isn't it called?

Comment: Maybe polyfills aren't set up correctly https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8012

Comment: It's properly registered on the page. Order is the same as what angular2 quick start suggests. No errors are visible in the console, so i assume everything is loaded properly.

Comment: do you see `i'm another!` when you navigate, it might not be navigating correctly, alternatively try navigating with `router.navigate` instead of `router.navigateByUrl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, you shouldn't bootstrap your components if you're planning to navigate to them using Angular2 router. You'll need to plan your navigation strategy in project planning stage. It'll be classic mode, meaning you'll have parent/child relationships and hide/show based on flags or routing mode, meaning you don't bootstrap or add component markups in their parent template and use angular's router instead. Angular itself will take care of all the navigation and showing/hiding of components automatically. All that's needed, is `RouteConfig` and bootstrapping your main component.

Also note, angular2 tutorials are not tailored to specific languages. If you have a website with path `www.something.com/angular/router` in ASP.NET MVC, your `/` in `RouteConfig` is NOT `www.something.com/` but the whole URL.

In regards to `RouteConfig` paths, you'll only need to define child navigations for each component.

Answer (score 0):

Your route to `Another` is a **non-terminal** route due to the use of the elipsis `...` on the end.

You need to include `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your templates so the router knows where to render.

You need to create a default route with path `/` in the `@RouteConfig` for `Another` if you want to navigate to it.

```
{ path: '/', name: 'AnotherDefault', component: AnotherDefault, useAsDefault: true }
```

The other option is to remove the `...` from the end of the path e.g. `path: '/Another'` if you want to navigate to it.

Comment: If i remove '...', i get an error "Child routes are not allowed for "/". Use "..." on the parent's route path." also 'Another' has children too.